# Linking Facebook and ParseUser (Parse.com)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am having a little trouble figuring out what my Login flow should be when utilizing Parse API's to link an existing Parse User and there Facebook account.

As of now, you can create a ParseUser and Login. I would like to allow the functionality to link a facebook account from within the app so that I can start to access facebook profiles for pictures/friends ect.

The code that is supplied by Parse.com to link ParseUsers is

```
            if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
              ParseFacebookUtils.link(currentUser, this, new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException ex) {
                  if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
                  }
                }
              });
            }
```

The only problem I am having though is that it does not allow me to use it inside a fragment class and the .link function has a error

```
The method link(ParseUser, Collection<String>, Activity) in the type ParseFacebookUtils is not applicable for the arguments (ParseUser, UserActivity, new SaveCallback(){})
```

**Any ideas what could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use that inside a Fragment, you just have to reference the upper level Activity.

The error is indicating that you aren't supplying the correct arguments for the method *Link*.  Based on what you have included, I believe you would want to call the *Link* method like so:

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_photos");
ParseFacebookUtils.link(currentUser, permissions, getActivity(), new SaveCallback() {...};
```

There are quite a few valid method signatures for *Link*, so if the above isn't what you are looking for then check out the rest here:
[Parse Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html)